# Open Linux subsystem directory v.s. raw Windows directory in VS Code?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I want to open a WSL directory in VS Code. What's the difference between the following two methods and which should I use?

1. First method, open WSL window. It's common.

[image]

2. Second method, directly open directory and select the directory in `wsl$` path.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Code recognize better the Connection than opening it directly

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30965986)

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, you'll want to use the *"New WSL Window"* (or its equivalent).  This utilizes the "*Remote - WSL"* extension to connect to your WSL instance through a small server that it installs in your WSL user's home directory.  You'll probably find it already installed in your case in `~/.vscode-server`.

This server handles the "translation" between the Windows VSCode and the Linux files, folders, and processes.

An easy way to think about the difference between the two methods of opening a folder:

- Using *"New WSL Window*" puts VSCode in "WSL/Linux" mode
- Using *"Open Folder"* and opening `\\wsl$\...` directly keeps VSCode in "Windows mode".

Comparing the two techniques with a real file.  I have a simple Python file in my WSL home directory that I wrote up for another answer a few days ago.  If I:

- Open my home directory through `\\wsl$\` in VSCode, then the VSCode Python extension complains:

  > `Python is not installed. Please download and install Python before using the extension.`

  Since I don't have the *Windows* version of Python installed, and VSCode is operating in "Windows mode", it can't find the Linux/WSL Python interpreter.

However, if I:

- Open my home directory through *"Remote-WSL: New WSL Window"*, then open my Python file, then VSCode finds my Python interpreter, and I can run and debug the file in WSL through VSCode.

---

Side note #1:  There is another method that has the same effect as using the command palette's *"New WSL Window"* -- From inside a WSL directory, run `code .`

Side note #2:  There may be times when you want to open a file that lives inside WSL in "Windows mode".  You may *want* to run it in a Windows version of a tool (Python, Java, whatever) to check compatibility.

As a general rule of thumb, however, you should probably do your Linux development with files inside WSL using VSCode's "WSL Mode" and Windows development with files that live on a Windows drive using "Windows (a.k.a. normal) mode".